# How can I conditionally show a menu only over a secure SSL connection?

Tags: php, ssl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use PHP to check if page was accessed with SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100189/use-php-to-check-if-page-was-accessed-with-ssl)

Is there any way to show up few menus only when the SSL is active with php?

Thanks

Comment: Using an `if` statement.

Answer (score 3):

You can check to see if [`$_SERVER['HTTPS']`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) is an empty string or not:

```
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']))
{
    echo '<a href="#">Secure Login</a>';
}
```

Comment: not with IIS, it sets $_SERVER["https"] to "on" or "off" so it isnt THAT easy.