# when inspecting the page security fields shows blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, https

> For our website The the security field is blank, what change want to
>   make for making security as "secure" , want to make it secure for cookies and requests.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer may give you an idea of the meaning of the secure flag in a cookie: [How does cookie "Secure" flag work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13729749/how-does-cookie-secure-flag-works)

In order to be able to flag the cookie as secure, you must implement a secure connection first. In short terms, you should switch to serve your website using HTTPS.